# How to run parsing logic of Pandas read_csv on custom data?

Tags: python, pandas

[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) contains a lot of parsing logic to detect and convert CSV strings to numerical and datetime Pythong values. My question is, is there a way to call same conversions also on a DataFrame which contains columns with string data, but where the DataFrame is not stored in CSV file but comes from a different (unparsed) source? So only a memory DataFrame object is available.

So saving such DataFrame to a CSV file and reading it back would do such conversion, but this looks very inefficient to me.

Comment: What you mean is that you have comma seperated values in a column as string? Or something else?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.to_numeric`?

Comment: There are multiple columns, each column is stringified value. For example, `"foobar"`, `"123"` and `"2019-01-01"` would be example values. DataFrame contains multiple columns and rows. I do not know which column is of which type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have e.g. a column of *string* type, but containing actually a date
(e.g. *yyyy-mm-dd*), you can use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert it to *Timestamp*.

Assuming that the column name is *SomeDate*, you can call:

```
df.SomeDate = pd.to_datetime(df.SomeDate)
```

Another option is to **apply** any own conversion function to any your column
(search the Web for description of *apply*).

You didn't give any details, so I can give only such very general advice.

Comment: But here I would have to detect myself which columns are Datetime and which numeric and which string?

Comment: In *read_csv*, when you want to apply any conversion utility, you **also** must specify, either column name or at least column index. The starting point to working with any tabular data is to know what data is in which column.

Comment: Not true. It parses strings into numbers automatically.

Comment: Of course, *read_csv* detects "only numbers" case on its own. It is even clever enough to tell apart integers from floats. But in other cases (e.g. *converters*) you have to specify the column.

Comment: So how do I run this smartness for integer and float detection outside of CSV parsing?

Comment: I think, you coud try *pd.to_numeric* function, on each column you need.
This function also checks whether input contains only integers or floats.
Probably you should use *errors='ignore'* parameter.